# MongoDB.Driver C# 2.0 Find (missing FindAll)

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to return all documents from the collection as IEnumerable. Please help! I receive an error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Products.DataLayer.ProductCategory]]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Products.DataLayer.ProductCategory]'.

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductCategory>> getAllCategories()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
        var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("productcategory");

        var documents = collection.Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();//.ContinueWith(e=>e.Result.AsEnumerable());
        documents.Wait();
        var b = documents.Result.AsEnumerable();
        IEnumerable<ProductCategory> ie = (IEnumerable<ProductCategory>)b;
        return ie;
    }
```

Comment: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Products.DataLayer.ProductCategory]'."

Comment: How I can deserialize that object in 2.0 version? I need an example pls.

Answer (score 2):

There are two points:

1. Define model in method `GetCollection<ProductCategory>`
2. Use `await` instead of `.Wait()` - this is not related to mongodb

   ```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductCategory>> getAllCategories()
   {
       var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
       var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
       var collection = database.GetCollection<ProductCategory>("productcategory");

       var documents = await collection.Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();
       return documents;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductCategory>> getAllCategories()
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
        var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<ProductCategory>("productcategory");

        var documents = collection.Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();//.ContinueWith(e=>e.Result.AsEnumerable());
        documents.Wait();
        var b = documents.Result.AsEnumerable();
        IEnumerable<ProductCategory> ie = (IEnumerable<ProductCategory>)b;
        return ie;
    }




    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var categoryService = new ProductCategoryService();
        var categoryDetails = categoryService.getAllCategories().Result;

        return View(categoryDetails);
    }
```